# randomise the values of three radio buttons producing a zero result

Tags: android, arrays, random

I keep getting a value of zero as the output of one of my radio buttons. I am trying to make the values from the radio buttons to display in a random order.

The main task is to randomise the order of various values
I gave the examples

the first option has a value of 2
the second option has a value of 3
the third option has a value of 1

I want to randomise the order of the the radio buttons.
I tried to have an an array of size 3 but got an ArrayOutOfBounds Exception.

I also dont want any of the question values repeated. for example

radio button 1 has a value of 2
radio button 2 has a value of 2
radio button 3 has a value of 1

Can i set if != null. I mean can I put some validation in to check to see if the particular array index has a value and if it doesn't ignore it.

```
    int opmin = 1;
    int opmax = 3;

    int randomoption  = opmin + (int)(Math.random() * ((opmax - opmin) + 1));
    int randomoption1  = opmin + (int)(Math.random() * ((opmax - opmin) + 1));
    int randomoption2 = opmin + (int)(Math.random() * ((opmax - opmin) + 1));










    int[] options = new int[4];
    choice = numberText + numberText2;
    answer = choice;
    options[0] = answer;
    options[3] = Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));
    radio.setText(String.valueOf(options[0]));
    choice1 = Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));

    radio1.setText(String.valueOf(options[1]));
    choice2  = Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));
    options[2] = choice2;
    radio2.setText(String.valueOf(options[2]));
```

Comment: That's probably because one of your random number ends up as 0 and as you don't have a value for `options[0]` the final text will be 0.

Comment: hi thanks but I used a range so why is it choosing zero.  with a max value of 3 and a min of 1. why is zero being chosen. Is there an easy solution to fix the problem.

Comment: My code should have worked, I think there is something else in your code that is the problem.

Comment: that is the whole method to generate the particular values. Is there anything you can see which could be causing issues.

Comment: instead of using random numbers to set the index should I loop through an array of 1 to 3 numbers in a random order I try and get your code working I will see if another value is being set elsewhere

Comment: could you repost your code for some reason it got deleted